# Haskell: is there a way of 'mapping' over an algebraic data type?

Tags: haskell, records, algebraic-data-types

Suppose that I have some simple algebraic data (essentially enums) and another type which has these enums as fields.

```
data Color  = Red   | Green  | Blue deriving (Eq, Show, Enum, Ord)
data Width  = Thin  | Normal | Fat  deriving (Eq, Show, Enum, Ord)
data Height = Short | Medium | Tall deriving (Eq, Show, Enum, Ord)

data Object = Object { color  :: Colour
                     , width  :: Width 
                     , height :: Height } deriving (Show)
```

Given a list of objects, I want to test that the attributes are all distinct. For this I have following functions (using `sort` from `Data.List`)

```
allDifferent = comparePairwise . sort
  where comparePairwise xs = and $ zipWith (/=) xs (drop 1 xs)

uniqueAttributes :: [Object] -> Bool
uniqueAttributes objects = all [ allDifferent $ map color  objects 
                               , allDifferent $ map width  objects
                               , allDifferent $ map height objects ]
```

This works, but is rather dissatisfying because I had to type each field (color, width, height) manually. In my actual code, there are more fields! Is there a way of 'mapping' the function

```
\field -> allDifferent $ map field objects
```

over the fields of an algebraic datatype like `Object`? I want to treat `Object` as a list of its fields (something that would be easy in e.g. javascript), but these fields have different types...

Comment: One could use scrap-your-boilerplate. For this simple case, I'm not sure that's much better.

Comment: You could factor it somewhat without generics: `uniqueAttributes objects = and [go color, go width, go height] where go :: (Ord a) => (Object -> a) -> Bool; go f = allDifferent (map f objects)`

Answer (score 6):

Here is a solution using [generics-sop](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/generics-sop):

```
pointwiseAllDifferent
  :: (Generic a, Code a ~ '[ xs ], All Ord xs) => [a] -> Bool
pointwiseAllDifferent =
    and
  . hcollapse
  . hcmap (Proxy :: Proxy Ord) (K . allDifferent)
  . hunzip
  . map (unZ . unSOP . from)

hunzip :: SListI xs => [NP I xs] -> NP [] xs
hunzip = foldr (hzipWith ((:) . unI)) (hpure [])
```

This assumes that the type `Object` you want to compare is a record type and requires that you make this type an instance of the class `Generic`, which can be done using Template Haskell:

```
deriveGeneric ''Object
```

Let's try to see what's going on here by looking at a concrete example:

```
objects = [Object Red Thin Short, Object Green Fat Short]
```

The line `map (unZ . unSOP . from)` converts each `Object` into a heterogeneous list (called an n-ary product in the library):

```
GHCi> map (unZ . unSOP . from) objects
[I Red :* (I Thin :* (I Short :* Nil)),I Green :* (I Fat :* (I Short :* Nil))]
```

The `hunzip` then turns this list of products into a product where each element is a list:

```
GHCi> hunzip it
[Red,Green] :* ([Thin,Fat] :* ([Short,Short] :* Nil))
```

Now, we apply `allDifferent` to each list in the product:

```
GHCi> hcmap (Proxy :: Proxy Ord) (K . allDifferent) it
K True :* (K True :* (K False :* Nil))
```

The product is now in fact homogeneous, as every position contains a `Bool`, so `hcollapse` turns it into a normal homogeneous list again:

```
GHCi> hcollapse it
[True,True,False]
```

The last step just applies `and` to it:

```
GHCi> and it
False
```

Answer (score 1):

For this very specific situation (checking a set of attributes that are simple sum types with 0-arity constructors), you can use the following construction using `Data.Data` generics:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}

module Signature where

import Data.List (sort, transpose)
import Data.Data

data Color  = Red   | Green  | Blue deriving (Eq, Show, Enum, Ord, Data)
data Width  = Thin  | Normal | Fat  deriving (Eq, Show, Enum, Ord, Data)
data Height = Short | Medium | Tall deriving (Eq, Show, Enum, Ord, Data)

data Object = Object { color  :: Color
                     , width  :: Width 
                     , height :: Height } deriving (Show, Data)

-- |Signature of attribute constructors used in object
signature :: Object -> [String]
signature = gmapQ (show . toConstr)

uniqueAttributes :: [Object] -> Bool
uniqueAttributes = all allDifferent . transpose . map signature

allDifferent :: (Ord a) => [a] -> Bool
allDifferent = comparePairwise . sort
  where comparePairwise xs = and $ zipWith (/=) xs (drop 1 xs)
```

The key here is the function `signature` which takes an object and generically across its immediate children calculates the constructor name of each child.  So:

```
*Signature> signature (Object Red Fat Medium)
["Red","Fat","Medium"]
*Signature>
```

If there are any fields other than these simple sum types, (like say an attribute of type `data Weight = Weight Int` or if you added a `name :: String` field to `Object`), then this will suddenly fail.

(Edited to add:)  Note that you can use `constrIndex . toConstr` in place of `show . toConstr` to use an `Int`-valued constructor index (basically, the index starting with 1 of the constructor within the `data` definition), if this feels less indirect.  If the `Constr` returned by `toConstr` had an `Ord` instance, there would be no indirection at all, but unfortunately...

Comment: Although converting constructors to strings and comparing them as such feels somewhat indirect, this solution has the virtue of being quite simple. It seems newer approaches to generics are all the rage, but `Data.Data` does the job!

Comment: I added a note about using `constrIndex` to get `Int`-valued indexes instead.  This is what I did originally, but using `show` gave a prettier (though admittedly less direct and less efficient) signature value.